# Load error messages in singleton bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have error_messages table, which contains the site-wide error messages.
I use the error messages across application. So, I created singleton bean of error messages (**ErrorMessagesLoad.java**)

**ErrorMessagesLoad** uses **ErrorMessageDao** to retrieve the error messages from database.

Should I create **static** variable in ErrorMessagesLoad to hold all the error messages and use it in all classes? or is there better way of doing it?

Thanks,
Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your own implementation of [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) in Spring to resolve any messages. [Here is](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/attachment/10261/JdbcMessageSource.java) a good point to start.

When implemented, you just wire your bean to any service or controller and it handles messages for you, with ability to iternationalize them.

Answer (score 0):

In general global static variables should be avoided.  Error handling can get tricky.  Many applications try to put a global catch handler somewhere near the top (e.g. web applications the top would be filters) which has the ErrorMessagesLoad injected into it.  That handler catches underlying exceptions, translates them into something user readable and then throws that higher.

Some examples include Spring's [exception translation filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html) and Jersey's [exception mapping](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.12/jax-rs.html#d4e435) mechanism.